# How to use factor analysis results to classification?

Tags: r, classification, pca, prediction, factor-analysis

After performing factor analysis by R as below, I get the results.

```
PCAVar <- principal(Corr, nfactors=7, rotate="varimax")
```

Below are all objects I can get:

```
names(PCAVar)

[1] "values"       "rotation"     "n.obs"        "communality"  "loadings"     "fit"          "fit.off"     
[8] "fn"           "Call"         "uniquenesses" "complexity"   "chi"          "EPVAL"        "R2"          
[15] "objective"    "residual"     "rms"          "factors"      "dof"          "null.dof"     "null.model"  
[22] "criteria"     "PVAL"         "weights"      "r.scores"     "rot.mat"      "Structure"
```

I want to use these factors in classifications. However, I do not know how to load factors to my training dataset.